# mysql query in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I would like to ask how can I can display only some data from a table to the user's view, using mysql query in cakephp.

Example, I have a table Students. There are two fields, name and age.

Clerk, 21 
 Mary, 23 
 Matt, 21 
 Clara, 21

Here is my query, `SELECT * FROM Students where age='21'`;

How and where can I apply it in cakephp? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) ... if you really want help, you're going to need to provide more info ... have you looked at the CakePHP book online ...

Either way, as a bit of a starter, somewhere in your controller you will:

```
$students = $this->Student->find('all',array('conditions' => array('age' => 21)));
$this->set('students', $students);
```

And then in your view:

```
foreach($students as $student){
    echo $student['Student']['name'] . ', ' . $student['Student']['age'] . '<br />';
}
```

Or something to that effect ...

Comment: hi. thanks for the response. i have tried to display the data using custom mysql query but i did not work. thanks again for replying. the answer u gave helps me a lot :)